# CSS gradients one sharp color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to fill a circle that will behave like a progress bar. But with this approach the edge is not sharp. How can i do this with dynamic width and not 50% 50%?

```css
.completion-indicator {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 30%, transparent 70%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.completion-indicator::before {
  content: '\2714';
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="completion-indicator"></div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about wanting to do CSS animation?

Comment: Not animation, I want the green color to be sharp and not "linear"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply **make the percentages the same.**

From [CSS Mine](http://www.cssmine.com/css3-gradients):

> The above-mentioned color patterns make use of the so-called **sharp transition**, which is not really a transition because there is a sharp edge between colors:
>
> ```
> background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, lightgreen 33%, darkgreen 33%)
> ```
>
> See [cdpn.io/e/licEd](http://cdpn.io/e/licEd)

For a 30% indicator:

```css
.completion-indicator {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 30%, transparent 30%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.completion-indicator::before {
  content: '\2714';
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="completion-indicator"></div>
```

You can then adjust the percentages as needed.

Here's an example with progress events simulated:

```js
var p = 0;
progress();
function progress() {
  document.querySelector(".completion-indicator")
    .style
    .background = "linear-gradient(to right, green " + p + "%, transparent " + p + "%)";
  p += 0.2;
  if (p < 100) {
    setTimeout(progress, 10);
  }
}
```

```css
.completion-indicator {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, transparent 0%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.completion-indicator::before {
  content: '\2714';
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="completion-indicator"></div>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nice! Added to post.

Answer (score 1):

Add another transparent color stop to the 30% edge, like this:

`background: linear-gradient(to right, green 30%, transparent 30%, transparent 70%)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set multiple `<color-stops>`

linear-gradient(to right, **green, green 30%, transparent 30%, transparent**)

When the color stops are at the same percentage, you effectively have a zero-width gradient.

[MDN Docs for Linear Gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

```
.completion-indicator {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green 30%, transparent 30%, transparent);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.completion-indicator::before {
      content: '\2714';
      color: grey;
}
```

Hope this helps!